# Why is that when I add in the following bootstrap my page become white?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a class project that required me to code a website that sells something. I'm trying to create the shopping cart so that when I click add to cart it should add the product. However, when I added in a bootstrap link my page becomes white. Is the bootstrap the problem or is it something wrong with my code?

My first time using this site so I'm not sure if this is all I need to post. If any other code is required (like the js) just ask. Thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Printing Prime</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favi.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
  <script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:100'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\splitslick\style.css">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    (problem***)
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <section id="" class="container-fluid cart">
        <article id="" class="col">
            <span class="open-modal">
                <i id="carts" class="fa fa-shopping-cart" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cart"></i>
            </span>
        </article>
    </section>

<section id="" class="container-fluid">
    <article id="" class="row">
         <div id="mask"></div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="cart" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Cart</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="show-cart table">

                </table>
                <div>Total price: $<span class="total-cart"></span></div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Order now</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>

  <section id="" class="container-fluid">
    <article id="" class="row">
      <div id="" class="col col-md-12">
        <nav class="navi">
          <ul class="list">
            <li><a href="#products">PRODUCTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#reviews">REVIEWS</a></li>
            <li style="padding: 10px; margin: 10px;"><a href="index.html"><img src="img/ppppp.png" id="logo"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT US</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>


  <section id="" class="container-fluid">
    <article id="" class="row">
      <div id="" class="col col-md-12">
        <div class="split-slideshow">
          <div class="slideshow">
            <div class="slider">
              <div class="item">
                <img src="img/banner1.png" />
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <img src="img/banner2.png" />
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fw800/background/20190222/ourmid/pngtree-blue-gradient-pattern-overlay-background-banner-image_50591.jpg" />
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <img src="img/banner4.jpeg" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slideshow-text">
            <div class="item"><a href="#" class="ss">PRINTING PRIME</a></div>
            <div class="item"><a href="#" class="ss">PRODUCTS</a></div>
            <div class="item"><a href="#" class="ss">THREE</a></div>
            <div class="item"><a href="#" class="ss">ABOUT US</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.12/jquery.mousewheel.js'></script>
        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js'></script>
        <script src="js/splitslick/js/index.js"></script>
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>

  <!-- <section id="" class="container-fluid">
  <article id="" class="row">
  <div id="" class="col col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-6">

</div>
<div clas="col-md-6">
<div class="col-lg-12">

</div>
</article>
</section> -->

<section id="products" class="container-fluid">
  <article id="" class="row">
    <div id="" class="col col-md-12 product-grid">
      <div class="col col-md-4 grid-item">
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <img style="height: 30vh; width: 15vw;" src="img/hat1.png" alt="Avatar">
              <h5 style="color:white;">Sad Face Cap</h5>
              <h5 style="color:white;">$12.99</h5>
              <div>
                  <input type="number" placeholder="# of items">
                  <a href="#" data-name="Sad Face Cap" data-price="12.99" class="add-to-cart btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-md-4 grid-item">
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <img style="height: 30vh; width: 15vw;" src="img/shirt1.png" alt="Avatar">
              <h5 style="color:white;">Signature Tee</h5>
              <div>
                <input type="number" placeholder="# of items">
                <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart" id="submit">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" col col-md-4 grid-item">
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <img style="height: 30vh; width: 14vw;" src="img/hoodie1.png" alt="Avatar" >
              <h5 style="color:white;">VHS Hoodie</h5>
              <div>
                <input type="number" placeholder="# of items" >
                <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart" id="submit">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>



  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: You appear to have four different jQuery versions included (`3.4.1`, `2.1.3`, `3.1.0` and `slim`). You only need one reference to jQuery (making sure it comes *before* Bootstrap). You also appear to reference Bootstrap twice (once from the CDN at the end of your `<head>`, and once at the start with a local reference). Removing these additional references, and making sure that Bootstrap comes *after* jQuery should fix your problem, though you'll also need Popper.JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be a few problems with the files you link:

- You appear to have four different jQuery versions included (`3.4.1`, `2.1.3`, `3.1.0` and `slim`). You only need one reference to jQuery (making sure it is referenced *before* Bootstrap). Having multiple references will throw errors.
- You also appear to reference Bootstrap twice (once from the CDN at the end of your `<head>`, and once at the start of your `<head>` with a local reference). Multiple Bootstrap references will also likely throw errors.
- You also appear to be missing a reference to [PopperJS](https://popper.js.org/), which is a required dependency of Bootstrap 4.
- `css\splitslick\style.css` is referenced with backslashes; you'll want forrward slashes.
- Your local `script.js` and `style.css` come *before* Bootstrap's JS and CSS, which means that Bootstrap will overwrite your own code; you'll want your code to be loaded *last*.

Removing these additional references, and making sure that Bootstrap
   comes *after* jQuery, PopperJS and Tether should fix your problem. Shifting your own JavaScript and CSS to the bottom of each respective section should cause it to override any conflicting Bootstrap code.

Here's a modified `<head>` that should work. Take note of the following order:

- Bootstrap 4 CSS -> Plugins -> Fonts -> Custom CSS
- jQuery -> PopperJS -> Tether -> Bootstrap 4 JS -> Custom JS

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Printing Prime</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favi.png">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css'>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:100'>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/splitslick/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
```